# Find the position of the digit after decimal point that is different between two numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula to find the position of the first digit after the decimal point that is different between two numbers, for example:

`5.4452` and `5.4413` will return to me `3` (i.e., the third number after the decimal point is different). Is there an easy way to do that in excel?

Thanks.

Comment: **What should the formula display if the values are exactly equal??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compares text versions of each number to 15 significant decimals:

```
=IF(A1=A2,"match", 
MATCH("diff", 
IF(MID(TEXT(A1,".000000000000000"),{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},1)<> 
MID(TEXT(A2,".000000000000000"),{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},1),"diff",) 
,0))
```

Here's Mark Balhoff's edit, which seems to work in all cases:

```
=IF(MOD($A1,1)=MOD($A2,1),"match",
MATCH("diff",
IF(MID(TEXT(MOD($A1,1),"0.000000000000000"),{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},1)<> 
MID(TEXT(MOD($A2,1),"0.000000000000000"),{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},1),"diff",)
,0))
```

Comment: Same comment I gave to Andy. Seems incorrect at first glance. Your formula gives a result of 4 for 5.2001 and 5.1999 when my understanding is the OP wants 1 returned there. (Because your difference is just 0.0002)

Comment: @MarkBalhoff, yeah I've gone through a couple of iterations. How's this one? First time I've gotten an upvote on a deleted answer :-)

Comment: Nice try but nope! 0.361 and 0.360636909 returns 2 when should be 3. 0.458580129 and 0.855135996 returns 2 when it should be 1. 0.012153885 and 0.718366846 returns 2 when it should be 1. (I am screening against some numbers I *somewhat* randomly generated).

Comment: Plus your formula changes its mind if you put more than one digit in front of the decimal. This can be easily fixed though by modding both numbers by 1 (assuming we only care about the mantissa).

Comment: Fixed your formula!!! I made two changes. As far as I can tell?! Adding the 4 Mod functions and adding the pre-decimal 0 to your text formats. 
`=IF(MOD($K5,1)=MOD($L5,1),"match", MATCH("diff",IF(MID(TEXT(MOD($K5,1),"0.000000000000000"),{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},1)<> MID(TEXT(MOD($L5,1),"0.000000000000000"),{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},1),"diff",),0))`

Comment: @MarkBalhoff, I can't get yours to work right now, not sure why. `MOD` makes sense. I'll look at it when I'm fresh. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look in K4:T17 of the [attached spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pf84mv04u6jf9sh/SO_Test_NumDiff.xlsm) for my testing. The green highlighted column (column R) is where I have what I posted before. Let me know if you find a pair of numbers that doesn't work out with this formula or an error in my testing.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff, that does work in every case you tested and a couple of others that I tried. Nice! I've edited the answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a simple way to do it, but if you really need to do it with Excel formulas and you can use auxiliary cells:

Assuming the two numbers in cells A4 and B4:

- Fill a row (let's assume 1) with consecutive numbers:

  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
- Fill cell B2 with the following formula:

  =(INT($A$4*10^A$1)=INT($B$4*10^A$1))*1

  and copy the formula do the right.
- The number you want is:

  =SUM(A2:J2)

If you want to check for more decimal places, just add more cells to the right.

EDIT: This return the total number decimal places you are checking for if the numbers are equal, and 0 if the numbers don't share the same integer portion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following **UDF**

```
Public Function compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Variant
    Dim l1 As Long, l2 As Long, i As Long
    If InStr(1, r1.Value, ".") = 0 Or InStr(1, r2.Value, ".") = 0 Then
        compare = "point missing"
        Exit Function
    End If
    v1 = Split(CStr(r1.Value), ".")(1)
    v2 = Split(CStr(r2.Value), ".")(1)
    l1 = Len(v1)
    l2 = Len(v2)
    For i = 1 To 9999
        If i > l1 Or i > l2 Then
            compare = "compare failed"
            Exit Function
        End If
        m1 = Mid(v1, i, 1)
        m2 = Mid(v2, i, 1)
        If m1 <> m2 Then Exit For
    Next i
    compare = i
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=compare(A1,A2)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I think if you are determined to accomplish this with a formula in Excel without writing VBA, the task may require some brute force. I am not saying there isn't a logarithmic manipulation to make this work (and I'm enough of a math nerd to mess around with this later) but you may end up stuck with brute force like the following:

```
=IF(ROUNDDOWN(K5,1)<>ROUNDDOWN(L5,1),1,IF(ROUNDDOWN(K5,2)<>ROUNDDOWN(L5,2),2,IF(ROUNDDOWN(K5,3)<>ROUNDDOWN(L5,3),3,IF(ROUNDDOWN(K5,4)<>ROUNDDOWN(L5,4),4,IF(ROUNDDOWN(K5,5)<>ROUNDDOWN(L5,5),5,0)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This **array formula**** seems to work:

=MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(IFERROR(0+MID(MID(A1:B1,FIND(".",A1:B1)+1,1000),ROW(INDIRECT("1:1000")),1),0),{1;-1})<>0,0)

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*